# How to get list of User Login information from MS-Graph API

Tags: onedrive, o365rwsclient, microsoft-graph-api

I need to call ms-graph to get a list of users logins in the last 24 hours and the ip address of the client from which they logged in from. Is that possible?

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 1):

Not today. 
Can you please open a request on user voice?: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/